# Replicating "text to columns " using a script

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I have a csv file with the following format. Currently this is all in one string

```
Column 1
Frame 0 adm2_score:0.957
Frame 1 dm2_score:0.942
Frame 2 _adm2_score:0.935
Frame 3 _adm2_score:0.940
Frame 4 _adm2_score:0.927
Frame 5 _adm2_score:0.925
```

However for my use case I want to separate the part of the string at ":" into a separate column like so

```
Column 1                            Column 2
Frame 0 _adm2_score:    0.957
Frame 1 _adm2_score:    0.942
Frame 2 _adm2_score:    0.935
Frame 3 _adm2_score:    0.940
Frame 4 _adm2_score:    0.927
Frame 5 _adm2_score:    0.925
```

Is there a way I can do this using a script (preferably python script) rather than manually doing it . Any help will be appreciated . (Note I know you can manually do this in excel but I want to do using a script as the data set is quite big.)

Comment: Assuming you want tab-separation, `sed -i 's/:/:\t/' file` will work just fine.

Comment: You could certainly do that with VBA. A trick I like is to use the "record macro" function, use the built in function (text to columns in your case), then look at the vba script that it generates. You can usually figure out how to edit it from there to do everything you need.

Comment: I have no experience with VBA could you provide a link which I can refer to get started ,Thanks

Comment: Have you tried writing some code yet?

Answer (score 1):

just replace : by :\t using python. Simple standalone demo:

```
z="""Frame 0 VMAF_feature_adm2_score:0.957
Frame 1 VMAF_feature_adm2_score:0.942
Frame 2 VMAF_feature_adm2_score:0.935
Frame 3 VMAF_feature_adm2_score:0.940
Frame 4 VMAF_feature_adm2_score:0.927
Frame 5 VMAF_feature_adm2_score:0.925""".splitlines()

for l in z:
    print(l.replace(":",":\t"))
```

you can read the file and put data to `z` with

```
z = open("input.txt","rb").read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` function to divide it where you want

```
for line in file:
   list = line.split(":")  ##turns into list at split at colon
   print list[0], ":  ", list[1]
```

Or something similar to easily get what you want

Answer (score 0):

For any one who is confused as to how to this here is one method I found using a python script

```
import csv, sys
z = open("output.csv","rb").read().splitlines()
for l in z:
    print(l.replace(":",","))
```

After that in commandline just run this

```
test.py > new.csv
```